# In Here Map - How to search a list of address

Tags: dictionary, location, maps, geocoding, here-api

I know how to get a location for one address, by example

```
function geocode(platform) {
            var geocoder = platform.getSearchService(),
                geocodingParameters = {
                    q:'Place  Armes, 78000 Versailles, Francia'                                                         
                };
            geocoder.geocode(
                geocodingParameters,
                onSuccess,
                onError
            );
        }
```

But if I have a list of address, ¿I need to call n times the same function with diferent q parameter? or exists any way to send a list of addresses in one call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a list of addresses with the Batch Geocoder API.
The list of addresses go into the body of a POST request. See the [Batch Geocoder API Guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#quick-start__send-a-request) for request construction details.

With the regular Geocoder API, you indeed need to send as many requests as you have addresses.